# Exclude one SKU from all cart price rules at once

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, sku, price-rules

I'm having trouble with this subject. I have one new SKU, where I would like none of my cart price rules to apply. Can somebody help me with this? It's a bit urgent :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the sku in your price rules. You can a) either set, that the rule doesn't get applied at all, when the mentioned product is in cart (Conditions) or you can b) set, that the sku is excluded from the rule (Actions).

**a) Conditions:**
If All of these conditions are false:
      If an item is found in the cart with all of these conditions true:
         SKU is ...

**b) Actions:**
If all of these conditions are true:
  SKU is not ....

Comment: Is there a way to do this all at once, or do I have to do it on every single price rule one-by-one?

Comment: This way you can only do it one-by-one unfortunately. You may write a small script that injects the conditions to every rule once or alternatively create an extension and hook into the rule calculation and exclude your either hardcoded or via settings given sku.